# Permit circle to be resized by not directly moved

Tags: leaflet

I'm working on a project where we need to create Search Rings. These are defined as a lat-long/radius, overlaid on a map of the Continental USA.

The desired implementation is a marker, useful for close positioning of the lat-long (or even updating, via popup + jQuery) with an "attached" circle.

Desired behavior:

1. when the marker is moved, the circle is dragged with it, and repositions itself with its center coincident with the marker's position (this is completed)
2. the circle's edge? may be gripped and resized, thus changing its radius.

Current issue: when a L.Circle is marked editable, it's both resizeable and directly movable. This is apparent by the gripper boxes on the outside of the circle together with the box at the center of the circle. How do I disable/hide that center gripper?

As always, thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet?  How are you making the circle editable?